# How can I create a footer like Jamendo's footer using CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a little confused about the footer of this site http://www.jamendo.com/ and how to create a similar footer to my site. It's really tricky.

Comment: My initial thoughts are that the white content area is a wrapper that has a higher z-index than the lower footer. The footer would be position: fixed; bottom: 0; and then pad the bottom of the wrapper with the same amount of px that the footer is tall..

Comment: What have you tried? What part of the footer's functionality are you struggling to copy? The way it appears when you scroll down? The tabs? The background colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. The all content (without footer) has a margin (in this example 240px), and the footer has position:fixed and height:240px, bottom:0

Answer (score 1):

The footer is position:fixed to the bottom of the screen at all times.

The content probably has a margin-bottom/padding-bottom of the appropriate pixels, and it is z-indexed to always be above the footer.

when you scroll down enough, the content ends and reveals the footer, which has always been there, fixed to your window's bottom.

good luck.

**EDIT:**

Also, when in doubt, use chrome's html inspector or Firefox's firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually not too complex, no JS just CSS. They have a footer fixed bottom of the page with a z-index lower then a sibling div called #container. Then they add margin-bottom: 240px; #container, so the page keeps scrolling into the empty margin to reveal the footer. Cool trick